# How to create a website which uploads/ download data from/ to Database and Excel files

Tags: database, excel

I am afraid to ask this kind of question as it has many factors to consider and its not easy for others to give suggestions.

But, I have to do this task and couldnt trace out the possible way to do this. One requirement I know is with the help of AJAX controls and Update panel ( I never worked on them) I have to do this.

Please please some ideas and suggstions, of how to start and soem pinpoints to get there.

it will be an internal portal site and users can access the data from this website which I have uploaded to the database and download data using UI I have.

hoping some help on this.

Thank you,
Ramm

Comment: Aditya: please can you clarify the technologies, business practices, and the workflow that you'd like to design?

Comment: Hi, I am using .NET 3.5, VS 2008 with SQL server 2008 technology. The proj is mainly for the Process flow in company. I mean how the proj's will be maintained and updating the parameters dynamically reg the proj.
Once the user updates any field in excel sheet, it should reflect the data in DB and viceversa.

Currently I know only this much abt the work to be done, in lower level I can explain once I get the full info of the work.
Thanks a lot for all your replies. 
I will take all of ur valuable suggestions
Thank You
Ramm

Answer (score 1):

You will need 2 components
1. Excel VBA : for retrieving data from web service and sending data to web service
2. Web Service : for providing data to excel vba and receiving data from excel vba for saving to database

I currently working for a project with this kind of mechanism, which involved database as backend and excel as user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example in PHP using MySQL - http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score -1):

You're right. That's way too much for anyone to try to answer.  But here are some links that should help:

Microsoft ASP.NET Ajax: http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax/

Db-driven ASP.NET App Tutorial: http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-363.aspx